# I get this error when I am trying to bing an image in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Icon' property not found on 'object' ''Detail' (HashCode=52423952)'. BindingExpression:Path=Icon; DataItem='Detail' (HashCode=52423952); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

what does this error mean and what is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the object `Detail` have an `Icon` property? if so can you please show the `Detail` object and your xaml code

Comment: That is what I was missing. Thanks:)

Comment: So, if it was answered, plz answer it and mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the Icon property in Detail object. Creating Icon property worked like magic !!